# Force select Dropdown option and reload page before page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

On a product list page of our store, we have (customer-facing) the ability to allow someone to select their Sort By in a dropdown box, one of the options being "A to Z."  Due to some constraints on our backend, we have no way of "forcing" the page to sort "A to Z," instead only sorting on "Most Popular" and a few other options.

The issue is that we do want this particular page to sort A to Z by default, and we want it to do so in a way that doesn't interfere with the guest.  So, the script would have to trigger before the page loads, select the A to Z sort from that drop down box, and then fire the page reload (or reload the page as soon as possible, so a customer doesn't see the page "double load" or anything).  Make sense?

I have no idea how to start with this javascript, but here's the drop down boxes options:

```
<div class="sortProductsMain">
<label id="sortById" class="sortProductsHeader">Sort By: </label>
<select id="sortSelection" dojoattachevent="onchange: doSort">
<option id="sortProductsDefault" class="sortProductsDefault" value="sortProductsDefault">Most Popular</option>
<option id="sortProductsHighestRated" class="sortProductsHighestRated" value="sortProductsHighestRated">Highest Rated</option>
<option id="sortProductsNewest" class="sortProductsNewest" value="sortProductsNewest">Newest</option>
<option id="sortProductsAToZ" class="sortProductsAToZ" value="sortProductsAToZ">A-Z</option>
<option id="sortProductsZToA" class="sortProductsZToA" value="sortProductsZToA">Z-A</option>
<option id="sortProductsPriceHighToLow" class="sortProductsPriceHighToLow" value="sortProductsPriceHighToLow">$$$-$</option>
<option id="sortProductsPriceLowToHigh" class="sortProductsPriceLowToHigh" value="sortProductsPriceLowToHigh">$-$$$</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly before the page loads you want the items in the select box to be sorted from a-z using javascript?

Comment: Why not hide the content via CSS as default until `sortProductsAToZ` is selected (via script, after `doSort` is available) and `doSort` is fired?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu - that is correct.

Comment: @Jay - That may be an excellent way to do it.  Again, I'm a beginner with Javascript, so an example of something along those lines may help me, but what you said does make sense to me.

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu: When the sort selection is changed, does it automatically load the page or do you need to press a button elsewhere?

Comment: I've stumbled on this: http://www.daftlogic.com/information-programmatically-preselect-dropdown-using-javascript.htm and the last bit of code (Post-Render Selection by Value) seems to do something similar to what I want.  As I haven't tested yet, I'm worried that it will select the value I want in the dropdown box (sortProductsAtoZ) but not actually fire the doSort...